# Accessing Eclipse Hono from a local network

Tags: minikube, eclipse-hono

We deployed Hono on a minikube cluster running on a virtual machine (CentOS 8). The load balancer is running and we can access and interact with Hono from within this virtual machine. However, we don't know how to access Hono from the outside, i.e. from our local network.

Is there some additional configuration required, like e.g. some sort of network bridge? We aren't very experienced with network setup and configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minikube is designed for local development in VM and it not intended to be accessed from the outside.

The easiest thing you could do to access it from the outside is to run minikube without a VM by starting it with:

```
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=None
```

And then you can expose the application with [Service of NodePort type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).